# Discord.js Add Role with Express | Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

Tags: express, routes, discord, discord.js

```js
app.get('/whitelist/*', function(req, res) {
     var fullUrl = req.originalUrl.replace('/whitelist/', '');
     const userjs = bot.users.cache.get(fullUrl);
     userjs.roles.add('791498271922585614');
});
```

I want to give a role to a user via Express using the code above, but it doesn't work. I receive the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to give a user a role, you'll need to get his [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) object.

To do that, you would have to get the [Guild](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild) object of the guild you're referring to.
You could simply do that using:

```
const guildObject = bot.guilds.cache.get('guild id here');
```

And finally, you could get the [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) object by typing:

```
const memberObject = guildObject.member(userjs); // AKA the user object you already have
```

Once that is done with, you can simply add the role using:

```
memberObject.roles.add('791498271922585614');
```